# Can I add "doctype:pdf" to a link usng java script (this is badly worded lol)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm trying to add a bookmarklet, so that every time I want to get a PDF of a book I can click on the bookmarklet type in the name of the book, hit enter then it'll get the name of so and so, all I have so far is:-

```
javascript:(function(){  var p=prompt('Search on Google:','');  if(p)  {     document.location.href='https://www.google.com/search?query=%27+escape(p)  }})();
```

Which I copied off a site. But I want to add more to it & I don't know how to use JavaScript for the life of me.

I just kept searching for stuff, till I got here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I assume you want a bookmarklet to search on google with PDF file type right? if so, this should do it:

```
javascript:(() => {
var p=prompt('Search on Google:','');
if (p) {
document.location.href=`https://www.google.com/search?query=${encodeURIComponent(p)}+filetype:pdf`;
}
})();
```